# How to format/color cells based on contents of other cells

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I am trying to automate an Excel workbook to help save time in making employee work schedules. I have two sheets. Sheet1 contains a simple table used to create the intended schedule for the month (employee name in first column, dates on the top row, and every day is marked with "WORKING", "ON CALL", "OFF", etc.), and the other sheet contains a table with color codes to keep track of how well the schedule was actually kept as the weeks pass. I need Sheet2 to update the color codes based on the schedule manually planned on Sheet1 so I can waste less company time manually color coding cells.

I don't want to use Conditional Formatting, since I believe you can't overwrite the format it gives a cell (in the case an employee called out rather than coming in on his scheduled day to work and on Sheet2 this needs to be recorded - with a different color code). I just need help figuring out some macro that can help speed things up and waste less company time manually color coding cells.

I don't want to record a macro this time, since names and days working can/will be different every time the schedule is updated/made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can work on.

Right click on the sheet 1 tab and select "View Code" copy and paste this code there.

Change a cell in Column A in sheet 1 to A,B or C then go to sheet 2 and see what happened.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target = "A" Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If Target = "B" Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        If Target = "C" Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works wonderfully! 
Is there a way to apply what that does to every [filled] column in the worksheet, in the case that more columns are added or removed for months of different lengths? I can't seem to get a loop to work for me. Or do loops not work in private subs..?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: This code works perfectly, but only for the first column (aka the first day of the schedule). I suppose I could copy and paste the code multiple times and increase the Target.Column number by one every time, in order to have the remaining columns under the same code (at least 31 columns, since the longest month would have 31 days to schedule), but I was wondering if there's a way to make the code do that without 31+ copies of the code you offered?
I was thinking along the lines of a loop until the last column is blank, but all my attempts won't work and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Instead `if target,column=1 then` use `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:C10")) Is Nothing Then` and set the range how ever big you want it.